# Como faço para adicionar bloco de artigo na minha tag section?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com dificuldade em adicionar uma tag section onde tenha 3 quadrados um ao lado do outro.

```css
section#blocos{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

section#blocos .blocos-coloridos{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 1% 0;
    padding: 2% 2%;
}
```

```html
<section id="blocos">
    <div class="bloco-coloridos">
        <h3>Vermelho</h3>
        <h4>Azul</h4>
        <h5>Verde</h5>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Seria interessante você adicionar um [mcve] na pergunta, e também a imagem diretamente aqui, assim fica mais facil te ajudar e a pergunta fica independente de links. :)

Comment: Vou programar e enviar

Comment: pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Borgesco Fiz uma resposta com base no que entendi na pergunta, vê se está solução, ajuda você?

Answer (score 0):

Basta dar um `float: right;` nos elementos internos da `div` `#bloco-coloridos`, ainda adicionei um `width: 33.33%` que divide exatamente igual em três partes o espaço!

```css
.bloco-coloridos > div{
  width: 33.33%;
  float: right;
}

#vermelho {
  background-color: red;
}

#azul {
  background-color: blue;
}

#verde {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section id="blocos">
  <div class="bloco-coloridos">
    <div id="vermelho">Vermelho</div>
    <div id="azul">Azul</div>
    <div id="verde">Verde</div>
  </div>
</section>
```